# Comparing array value (int) from database to an integer in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, integer, comparison, sitemap

The problem is fairly simple, yet hard to quite explain. I'm pulling the data 'url' and 'section' from a database. The 'section' value is an integer. I'm pulling all of this data into another array to be displayed onto another page. (This is a sitemap generator)

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT url, section FROM table WHERE section <= 3";
    $result = db_query($query, $dbh);

    $dynamic_urls = array();
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $dynamic_urls[] = "http://example.com/" . checkSection() . $row['url'];
    }

    function checkSection(){
        if ($row['section'] == 1)
        {
            return "web/";
        } 
        elseif ($row['section'] == 2)
        {
            return "email/";
        } 
        elseif ($row['section'] == 3){
            return "print/";
        }
        return "FAILED/";
    }

    ?>
```

I believe the problem is that in the checkSection() method is having trouble comparing the array value $row['section'] to an integer (1, 2, 3) as shown. The output file just loops through the array $dynamic_urls and prints them to a page, here is some example output:

> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink1
>
> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink2
>
> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink3
>
> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink4
>
> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink5
>
> http://example.com/FAILED/example_permalink6

I'm needing those 'FAILED' outputs to be the relevant 'web/', 'email/', or 'print/' titles that I'm looking for.

Why is my if statement having trouble comparing $row['section_id'] to an integer?

Comment: You need to pass `$row` into `checkSection()` - it's out of scope.

Comment: So, changing the initial declaration of checkSection to checkSection($row) works? or checkSection($row['section_id'])?

Comment: the former will do it - see the answer from Kelly John Rose

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your row isn't being received within the scope of your function.

```
function checkSection(){
    if ($row['section'] == 1)
    {
        return "web/";
    } 
    elseif ($row['section'] == 2)
    {
        return "email/";
    } 
    elseif ($row['section'] == 3){
        return "print/";
    }
    return "FAILED/";
}
```

To the function, $row is blank. You need to pass it as a variable to the function for this to work.

ie.

```
function checkSection($row){
    if ($row['section'] == 1)
    {
        return "web/";
    } 
    elseif ($row['section'] == 2)
    {
        return "email/";
    } 
    elseif ($row['section'] == 3){
        return "print/";
    }
    return "FAILED/";
}

checkSection($row)
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I need to get more sleep at night, I was bashing my head wondering what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Not a problem, it's a surprisingly easy mistake to make when you start working with PHP from a functional perspective.